# Asynchronous returning of values to parent process

Tags: c, process, fork, child-process

I'm involved in the resolution of an exercise using fork. The statement is this: 1 parent creates 3 children, those have random and different execution times and they have to return their respective values to the parent. So, till now I'm capable to create and execute the child processes and capture SOME of their values, but the execution becames nuts after that. The code I got till now is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAXCAPOS 3
#define MAXCOMERCIOS 3

/* Funcion que calcula aleatorios */
int calculaAleatorios(int min, int max) {
    return rand() % (max-min+1) + min;
}

/* Funcion para dar más tiempo a que los negocios paguen */
void darPlazo() {
    printf("\nDON: ¡Chicos! Decidle a los comerciantes que me deben dinero, que como no paguen lo que me deben, la semana que viene quemare sus tiendas.");
}

/* Funcion para dar una leccion a los negocios */
void darLeccion() {
    printf("\nDON: ¡Chicos! Quemad los comercios que no han pagado esta semana.");
}

/* Funcion para generar un consejo */
void generaConsejo() {
    sleep(10);
    if(calculaAleatorios(0,1)==0) {
        printf("\nConsigliere: Ya he deliberado SIGUSR1");       
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
    } else {
        printf("\nConsigliere: Ya he deliberado SIGUSR2");
        kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
    }
}

int main(void){
  pid_t pidDon;
  pid_t pidCapo[MAXCAPOS];
  pid_t pidConsigliere;
  int i = 1, j = 1;
  int totalImpagos = 0;
  for (i; i <= MAXCAPOS; i++){
    /* Forkeando pidDon para obtener los capos */
    switch (pidDon = fork()){
      case -1:
        perror("Error en la llamada a la funcion fork()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
      case 0:
      {
        int noPagan = 0, tiempo = 0;
        pidCapo[i] = getpid();
        srand(pidCapo[i]); /*Generamos una semilla por el pid, dentro del proceso hijo para obtener semillas diferentes*/
        printf("\nDON: Contrato al capo%d (pid: %d)", i, pidCapo[i]);
        /* VISITAR LOS COMERCIOS Y RECIBIR CUANTOS HAN PAGADO (int) */
        for (j; j <= MAXCOMERCIOS; j++){
          tiempo = calculaAleatorios(5, 10); /* Genera un tiempo aleatorio entre 5 y 10 */
          printf("\n Capo%d: %d Segundos para despertar (pid: %d)", i, tiempo, pidCapo[i]);
          sleep(tiempo);
          printf("\n Capo%d: Visita el comercio %d (pid: %d)", i, j, pidCapo[i]);
          if (calculaAleatorios(0, 1) == 0){
            printf("\n Capo%d: El comercio %d no me ha pagado, malditas ratas!! (pid: %d)", i, j, pidCapo[i]);
            noPagan++;
          } else {
            printf("\n Capo%d: El comercio %d ha pagado (pid:%d)", i, j, pidCapo[i]);
          }
        }
        printf("\nCapo%d: tengo %d morosos", i, noPagan);
        exit(noPagan);
        break;
      }
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  /*Proceso DON*/
  // Crear señales
  printf("\nDON: Voy a esperar noticias de mis capos... (pid: %d)", getpid());
  signal(SIGUSR1, darPlazo); // Unimos la señal SIGUSR1 a su procedimiento
  signal(SIGUSR2, darLeccion); //Unimos la señal SIGUSR2 a su procedimiento
  if (pidDon != 0 && pidDon != -1){
    for (i = 1; i <= MAXCAPOS; i++){
      int retorno;
      waitpid(pidCapo[i], &retorno, 0);
      retorno = WEXITSTATUS(retorno);
      printf("\nDON: Al capo %d no le han pagado %d comercios", i, retorno);
      totalImpagos += retorno;
    }
    sleep(30);
    if (totalImpagos == 0){
      printf("\nDON: Que bien, esta vez han pagado todos :D");
      printf("\nDON: He terminado mi dia\n");
      return (0);
    } else {
      if (totalImpagos == 1){
        printf("\nDON: No me ha pagado 1 comercio, grrrrrrrr!!!!");
      }
      if (totalImpagos > 1){
        printf("\nDON: No me han pagado %d comercios, estoy muy encabronado!", totalImpagos);
      }
      printf("\nDON: Consultare con mi consigliere");
      /*Proceso Consigliere*/
      pidConsigliere = fork();
      if (pidConsigliere == -1){
        perror("\nFallo al crear el proceso Consigliere");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      else if (pidConsigliere == 0){
        signal(SIGUSR1, generaConsejo); // Unimos la señal SIGUSR1 a su procedimiento
        printf("\nConsigliere: Hola Don! Espero tu señal");
        pause();
        exit(0);
      }
      /*Vuelta al DON*/
      // Consulta al consigliere
      sleep(5);
      printf("\DON: Le mando una señal a mi consigliere");
      if (kill(pidConsigliere, SIGUSR1) == -1){ // Lanzamos kill contra pidConsigliere y evaluamos el error
        perror("\nFallo al enviar la señal al Consigliere");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      printf("\nDON: Esperare mientras mi consigliere delibera");
      pause();
    }
  }
  printf("\nDON: He terminado mi dia\n");
  return (0);
}
```

So, I need to know how to retreive correctly all the 3 returned values. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. In English please!

Answer (score 0):

What about installing a signal handler for `SIGCHLD` in the parent and when it is invoked, reap the child's exit status with `wait()`, `waitpid()` or `wait4()`?

That's the canonical practice. I'm not exactly sure what the purpose of the `SIGUSR1/2` is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

> So, till now I'm capable to create and execute the child processes and
>   capture SOME of their values, but the execution becames nuts after
>   that.

You are indexing `pidCapo[i]` with values for `i` from `1` to `MAXCAPOS`, which is wrong because arrays are indexed from `0` on.